# Spyder python: Skip printing all code when using "run current cell"

Tags: python, console, spyder

When I use "run current cell" or "run selection" the compiler print ALL the code it will run to the console and then runs it.

Any way to supress this? I dont want to flood the console with all this non-useful information. I know what code i ran, I don't need it repeated (i just need it to run:).

Comment: How does this work in other IDEs?

Comment: I don't know since I've never used python before i started using spyder, but i dont see why all the code must be printed prior to running it (since this is not needed when running the entire script, only when running a cell.

Comment: I was kind of opposed to this before, but now I'm leaning towards it because it doesn't make much sense to copy cell contents all the time to the console. However, as I told you before, this is not going to be a feature for Spyder 3.2, maybe for version 4.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I do think this would be appriciated as a feature, maybe in options a checkbox to display or not display all code before you run it?

When often running large cells (which i do) this really floods the console and makes finding the relevant info (such as compiling errors) much harder.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I second having an option to suppress cell code printing to console.

Comment: There's already some work to solve this in Spyder 4.

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, there is no way to not print cells in the IPython console in any version of Spyder 3.

However, we are working to make this possibility available in Spyder 4, to be released in 2019.

Comment: Carlos, I am surprised that this is not optional. It is quite ugly and not useful.